# Web browser not loading from bfcache always

Tags: javascript, html, reload, back-button

I have an e-commerce application that is built on JavaScript and HTML for the front end (uses gulp to bundle). I am facing an issue with it while returning to a page from the back button. On most occasions, the page would simply rerun all the javascript that was initially executed to construct the page. In some rare cases, it behaves as expected which is no JS is executed when the page is hit by pressing the back button on the browser. I confirm that there are no meta headers or response headers that will invalidate the cache. I can see that the rerun is initiated by the browser and not by any of my JS codes. Could someone shed some light on what could cause this to happen?

Comment: Aren't you using the `popstate` event?